# Script is not showing up in the GIMP Plugin Browser

Tags: python, gimp

Python and GIMP newbie,
I put it in 2.0 plug-ins folder and made it executable, not showing any errors, or anything
please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Generate Images with text in a batch from a text file
import re 
from gimpfu import *

def get_valid_filename(s):
    s = str(s).strip().replace(' ', '_')
    return re.sub(r'(?u)[^-\w.]', '', s)

def generate_images(template_path, text_path, font, 
    x_center, y_center, size, color, output_path):

    file = open(text_path)
    text = file.read()
    file.close()
    text = text.split('\n')
    text = [l for l in text if len(l)>0]

    template = pdb.gimp_file_load(template_path,template_path)

    for line in text:

        # Make a new image. Size 10x10 for now -- we'll resize later.
        img = pdb.gimp_image_duplicate(template)#gimp.Image(1, 1, RGB)

        # Save the current foreground color:
        pdb.gimp_context_push()

        # Set the text color
        gimp.set_foreground(color)

        words = line.split(' ')

        for word,idx in zip(words,range(len(words))):

            # Create a new text layer (-1 for the layer means create a new layer)
            layer = pdb.gimp_text_fontname(img, None, 0, 0, word, 10,
                                           True, size, PIXELS, font)

            layer.translate(int(0.5*(img.width-layer.width)+x_center), 
                            int(0.5*(img.height-layer.height)+y_center+100*idx))

        # Resize the image to the size of the layer
        #img.resize(layer.width, layer.height, 0, 0)

        # Background layer.
        # Can't add this first because we don't know the size of the text layer.
        #background = gimp.Layer(img, "Background", layer.width, layer.height,
        #                        RGB_IMAGE, 100, NORMAL_MODE)
        #background.fill(BACKGROUND_FILL)
        #img.add_layer(background, 1)

        new_image = pdb.gimp_image_duplicate(img)
        layer = pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(new_image, CLIP_TO_IMAGE)
        line_filename = get_valid_filename(line)
        pdb.gimp_file_save(new_image, layer, output_path+line_filename+'.png', '?')
        pdb.gimp_image_delete(new_image)


register(
    "python_fu_batch_text",
    "Add list of text to a batch of image templates",
    "Create a new image with your text string",
    "Peter Whidden",
    "Peter Whidden",
    "2017",
    "Generate batch images from text file",
    "",      # Create a new image, don't work on an existing one
    [
        (PF_STRING, "source", "Template Image", "/some/path/image.png"),
        (PF_STRING, "string", "Source Text", '/path/file.txt'),
        (PF_FONT, "font", "Font face", "Sans"),
        (PF_SPINNER, "x", "X Offset", 0, (-50000, 50000, 1)),
        (PF_SPINNER, "y", "Y Offset", 0, (-50000, 50000, 1)),
        (PF_SPINNER, "size", "Font size", 50, (1, 3000, 1)),
        (PF_COLOR, "color", "Text color", (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
        (PF_STRING, "destination", "Output Destination", "/path/dir/")
    ],
    [],
    generate_images, menu="<Image>/File/Create")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me...

[image]

A common problem is a python syntax error, typically an indentation error, but all the cutting-and- pasting between your code and mine could have fixed it. You can weed out the worst problems by just running your plugin in a terminal:

```
python the_code.py
```

The worst syntax errors are caught there. If it says it's missing `gimpfu` then you are good (`gimpfu` is only available under Gimp).

Then you can add a

```
print "************* Registering"
```

just before the call to "register" in your code. Then if you start Gimp from the terminal it should show up there if Gimp runs the plugin to make it register on startup. Syntax errors at runtime will also appear there.

Note that Gimp doesn't register the script every time it starts: after a successful registration it keeps the time stamp of the executable and re-registers only if the file timestamp is different from the recorded one. You can check the registration state of your plugin in the `pluginrc` file (plain text file, in `~/.config/GIMP/2.10` in the current versions on Linux).

PS: Gimp still uses Python V2 which is now deprecated. On recent Linux distros (in particular Ubuntu and derivatives since 20.04) Python v2 may not be available by default and Gimp is installed without Python support. To check Python support, see if you have a `Python-fu` entry at the bottom of your `Filters` menu:

[image]

If it's not there then Python is not available. There are ways to reinstate support but this would be outside the scope of this answer. See [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Heal-Selection-Missing-from-Gimp-on-Ubuntu-20-04?pid=18351#pid18351) for some ways.

PS: in Python V2 the division between integers is an integer division, so your `int(.5*(expression))` can be replaced by `(expression)/2`.